# how do I disable a nic permanently in Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: networking

When I turn off nic in Network Settings GUI it comes back on after rebooting in Ubuntu Desktop. I need to do this to instances of 18.04, deployed as guest VMs in VMware. I'm trying to do this using the GUI only, and I would think it should be supported. I looked on help.ubuntu.com and do not see a clear answer.

There are two NICs that show up, ens160 and ens192, by default using DHCP. To relieve pressure on IP address allocation in the organization, I wanted to permanently turn off ens192. Then for ens160, I'll be setting it statically using addresses allocated for my purposes.

So in the GUI I turn the NIC off; close the window; verify it is gone with ifconfig in a terminal window, and then reboot. It however comes back on after reboot, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be, for something that survives reboot, is to uncheck "Connect automatically" on the Wired GUI screen, on the "Details" tab. I'm supposing the "Connection Profile" is what keeps track of this. Ubuntu online help does not seem to explain any of this well, or at least I can't find relevant documentation.